# Git flow - Why using/maintaining master branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

It seems Git-Flow as implemented below is quite popular.

[image: Git Flow]

Now imagine the master branch is gone : the feature branch is created from develop and then merged back to develop... Just like the good old Git-Flow.

When you need to release your code, you just create the release branch from develop and then merge back to develop **only** and of course, you do not forget to create a tag.

So unlike standard Git-Flow, no merge from release branch to master and the tag is created on develop.

If you decide to create a hotfix, you can just create your hotfix branch from the tag on develop.
Creating a hotfix from master may not be a good idea : if the actual prod version is 0.1 but another release 0.2 has been build and sent to user-acceptance environment then master will be equal to version 0.2 and **not** the actual prod version (0.1)

It think it is a common confusion with Git-Flow, master is production-ready code not necessarily THE production code.

My question is : Why do we need to maintain master branch ? What is the added value ?

Thank you

Comment: I honestly don't know. I'd be interested in seeing an explanation. My best guess is that people not very familiar with Git feel "safer" when there is a branch. However, Git's understanding of branches is different - any addressable commit *is* a branch. Add a named tag and you have a branch. So if you tag your releases, you have "release branches" automatically. A master branch is indeed unnecessary if you just tag the stable versions of develop.

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](http://endoflineblog.com/oneflow-a-git-branching-model-and-workflow). Somebody implemented just that - dropped master and worked with the rest. He's calling the it "OneFlow". (To be more precise, it drops master and renames develop to master. But I tend to think of it as keeping develop for simplicity)

Comment: Thank you, very interesting reading.

Answer (score 1):

`Why do we need to maintain master branch ? What is the added value?`

Let me re-use the already linked article (thanks to VLAZ!):
There is a discussion going on about `--no-ff` helping the readability or not.
Using this option leads to the `develop` branch only consisting of merge commits of features and therefore being an ordered list of all features implemented in integrated into the product.

Your `master` branch is nothing else: an ordered list of all releases ever made.
Do you necessarily need it? Definitely not.
Is it maybe helpful anyway for some projects / teams? Sure!

It's up to your team to adjust this `framework` to whatever your needs are.
Maybe something more lightweight - like [Github flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) - is a better approach for you.

Both ways are perfectly acceptable and there is - like always - no one-size-fits-all. ;)